# Как добавить свои языки в базу данных с помощью waavi для laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Занимаюсь учебным проектом на Laravel. Я должен сделать мультиязычную локализацию с возможностью добавления и редактирования языка пользователем. Локализацию с использованием файлов сделал. Нагуглил пакет waavi https://github.com/Waavi/translation/blob/master/readme.md#managing-database-languages который, как мне показалось, поможет найти решение к моему заданию. Все установил, миграции выполнил, застрял на пункте "Add your languages of choice to the database". Как это сделать? Кроме этого, может кто-то подскажет что делать дальше? Как сделать добавление языка пользователем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен в правильности решения, но не нашел другого пути. Добавил языки вручную в базу. После этого команда "php artisan translator:load" все равно не сработала. На помощь пришла чудо команда "composer update". Вот после этого сработал "load" и в базе заполнилась таблица "translator_translations". Но и это не все. Изменил текст перевода в файле и в базе чтобы проверить откуда тянет перевод. Оказалось остался первоначальный вариант.., который уже нигде не существует. Он остался в кэше. Чтобы устранить недочет отключил пользование кэша в \config\translator.php
в строке 'enabled' => env('TRANSLATION_CACHE_ENABLED', false).